# Items missing from desktop when using rdp

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, mate-panel

I access Ubuntu 22.04 Mate from Windows remote desktop. When I log in, the top and bottom bars are missing from the desktop. While searching for a solution, I found that the command mate-panel --replace would bring up the missing menu and bottom bars, but if I close that terminal window the bars disappear. How can I make them permanent? thanks.

Comment: Try the following. Create a (hidden) file `.xsessions` in the home directory, with the following contents -- `mate-session &`. After that, reboot and try reconnecting.

Comment: OK, did that. Now the desktop is there, but without any icons on it. the menu is there, but when I click on it, the list appears but quickly disappears and I can't access any selection. What now?

Comment: Try adding the line mate-panels --replace at the end of the .xsessions file